# How to solve "cannot open file 'LIBCD.lib' " in visual studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

trying to compile some code i downloaded, i get link error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCD.lib'. i cant find this file anywhere on my computer. what is it, and can i download it from somewhere? is there another way to get the code to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [first hit on Google for `libcd`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/48340163-9e9b-4ada-a64d-f69bb3e242a6/) says:

> This file is the static library for the debug single threaded version
>   of the C runtime. Visual Studio 2005 no longer supports this version
>   of the C runtime: instead you need to use the multi-threaded version
>   (libcmtd.lib) or the dynamically linked (DLL) version (msvcrtd.lib).
>
> To fix this problem you will need to change the makefile that comes
>   with GLUI to get it to use a different version of the library.

and some other things that might help you.

Comment: Not always you have the chance to recompile your lib. If it is a 3rd party lib then you're hosed.

Comment: as OP said "trying to compile some code i downloaded" the downvote might not be entirely justified...

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I only wrote "LIBCD.lib" in `Configuration Properties` -> `Linker` -> `Input` -> `Ignore Specific Library`

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this from the project settings. You need to add the /NODEFAULTLIB to the linker settings:

core.2f.nodefaultlib.asp">http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vccore/html/*core*.2f.nodefaultlib.asp

This option will make the linker ignore all the /DEFAULTLIB directives - this will remove the dependency on libcd.lib. Unfortunately it will remove all the other dependencies as well so you will need to explicitly add the libraries you do need (like glut32.lib etc.) as inputs to the linker.